# Sum values of each key in list of dictionaries python

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries which is coming from Django query set.

Like this:

```
email_sent_count = [
  {
    'second_follow_count': 1,
    'first_follow_count': 1,
    'initial_count': 1,
    'third_follow_count': 0
  },
  {
    'second_follow_count': 1,
    'first_follow_count': 0,
    'initial_count': 1,
    'third_follow_count': 1
  },
  {
    'second_follow_count': 1,
    'first_follow_count': 1,
    'initial_count': 1,
    'third_follow_count': 1
  }
]
```

Now, I want the sum of each key separately.

like this:

`inital_contact = 3
first_followup = 2
second_followup = 3
third_followup = 2`

I am trying the following solution:

```
initial_contact = sum(map(lambda x: x['initial_count'], email_sent_count))
first_followup = sum(map(lambda x: x['first_follow_count'], email_sent_count))
second_followup = sum(map(lambda x: x['second_follow_count'], email_sent_count))
third_followup = sum(map(lambda x: x['third_follow_count'], email_sent_count))
```

But now, I'm getting 11 keys in all dictionaries and I'm implementing 11 lambda function so is there any good way to solve this issue rather than calling 11 times lambda function

By following ORM I getting above email_sent_count

```
i = Q(inital_contact__range=(from_date, to_date))
f1 = Q(first_followup__range=(from_date, to_date))
f2 = Q(second_followup__range=(from_date, to_date))
f3 = Q(third_followup__range=(from_date, to_date))

email_count = campaign_contact.filter(i | f1 | f2 | f3).annotate(initial_count=Count('inital_contact'),
                                                             first_follow_count=Count('first_followup'),
                                                             second_follow_count=Count('second_followup'),
                                                             third_follow_count=Count('third_followup'),
                                                             ).values('initial_count', 'first_follow_count',
                                                                      'second_follow_count', 'third_follow_count'
```

So, is there is a solution which is directly working with ORM ?

Comment: All of the answers right now work on the dicts, but the better (and faster) way to do this would be to do this in the database: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: edited. Added ORM query..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I changed the ORM query that gets me the exact result:

ORM looks like this:

```
email_sent_count = campaign_contact.filter(i | f1 | f2 | f3
                                      ).annotate(initial_count=Count('inital_contact'),
                                                 first_follow_count=Count('first_followup'),
                                                 second_follow_count=Count('second_followup'),
                                                 third_follow_count=Count('third_followup')
                                                 ).aggregate(initial_sum=Sum('initial_count'),
                                                             first_follow_sum=Sum('first_follow_count'),
                                                             second_follow_sum=Sum('second_follow_count'),
                                                             third_follow_sum=Sum('third_follow_count'))
```

output...

```
{'third_follow_sum': 2, 'second_follow_sum': 3, 'first_follow_sum': 2, 'initial_sum': 3}
```

So, there is not for loops, no lambda... I think performance wise it will work.

And Thanks to all to provide me the solutions, by looking other solution I'm able to solve this. :)

Answer (score 4):

if you don't mind getting a dictionary as result you could use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#defaultdict-examples) like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

sums = defaultdict(int)
for item in email_sent_count:
    for key, value in item.items():
        sums[key] += value
```

which results in

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, 
            {'second_follow_count': 3, 'initial_count': 3, 
             'first_follow_count': 2, 'third_follow_count': 2})
```

and you can access the individual sums just like a dictionary: `sums['second_follow_count']`.

...or maybe even better with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#counter-objects):

```
from collections import Counter

sums = Counter()
for item in email_sent_count:
    for key, value in item.items():
        sums[key] += value

# Counter({'second_follow_count': 3, 'initial_count': 3,
#          'first_follow_count': 2, 'third_follow_count': 2})
```

Comment: Thanks... This works for me..!!
I have added ORM query as well. There is nested loop but I have large amount of data that will slow down the process so, if ORM can be changed it's good for me

Answer (score 0):

Or if you prefer do do it yourself without using Counter or DefaultDict:

```
from pprint import pprint
email_sent_count = [
  {
    'second_follow_count': 1,
    'first_follow_count': 1,
    'initial_count': 1,
    'third_follow_count': 0
  },
  {
    'second_follow_count': 1,
    'first_follow_count': 0,
    'initial_count': 1,
    'third_follow_count': 1
  },
  {
    'second_follow_count': 1,
    'first_follow_count': 1,
    'initial_count': 1,
    'third_follow_count': 1
  }
]

# create empty dict with all keys from any inner dict and initialized to 0
alls  = dict( (x,0) for y in email_sent_count for x in y)  
pprint(alls)

for d in email_sent_count:
    for k in d:
        alls[k] += d[k]

pprint(alls)
```

Output:

```
{'first_follow_count': 0,
 'initial_count': 0,
 'second_follow_count': 0,
 'third_follow_count': 0}

{'first_follow_count': 2,
 'initial_count': 3,
 'second_follow_count': 3,
 'third_follow_count': 2}
```